# Get-AutomationPSCredential not Available within Azure Function App

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-function-app

I am getting the error below:

```
2020-09-17T10:05:00.724 [Error] ERROR: Error logging into WVD: The
term 'Get-AutomationPSCredential' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.Exception             :Type    :
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptionMessage : Error
logging into WVD: The term 'Get-AutomationPSCredential' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.HResult :
-2146233087CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId :
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,_TimerTrigger1_InvocationInfo
:MyCommand       : _TimerTrigger1_HistoryId       : 1InvocationName  :
_TimerTrigger1_CommandOrigin   : InternalScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1: line
158Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException : Result:
ERROR: Error logging into WVD: The term 'Get-AutomationPSCredential'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.Exception     
:Type    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptionMessage :
Error logging into WVD: The term 'Get-AutomationPSCredential' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.HResult :
-2146233087CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId :
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,_TimerTrigger1_InvocationInfo
:MyCommand       : _TimerTrigger1_HistoryId       : 1InvocationName  :
_TimerTrigger1_CommandOrigin   : InternalScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1: line
158Exception: Error logging into WVD: The term
'Get-AutomationPSCredential' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.Stack:
```

I have seen information online that suggests it is part of the module "AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit", but I don't understand how I install this into the environment the Function App runs in.stuff and am following a blog post below to try and get the auto-start up shut down working. I am fairly certain that I have followed this correctly. To me the error suggests that the environment doesn't have the module loaded.

https://www.ciraltos.com/auto-start-and-stop-session-hosts-in-windows-virtual-desktop-spring-update-arm-edition-with-an-azure-function/

Comment: Can you share the entire error?  It's truncated. Also, did you create the credential first, as seen here?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials#create-a-new-credential-asset .  One thing to try, add this to the top of your script `Import-Module -Verbose Az.Automation`.  This module should already be there for you in Azure Automation.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the full error stack. I tried the import statement and could see it importing the various functions, but still get the same error. I haven't tried creating a credential. I was looking at that, but not sure how it fits in this example, it says on that same page about using Get-AutomationPSCredential. I will look into the answer below, but will not have time available now until next week.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the command  `Get-AutomationPSCredential` in the azure function, it is an [Internal cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#internal-cmdlets) belongs to the internal module `Orchestrator.AssetManagement.Cmdlets`, it is only available when you're executing runbooks in the Azure sandbox environment, or on a Windows Hybrid Runbook Worker.

So in your case, your option is to use the script in the [automation powershell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks), then use `Invoke-WebRequest` in the timer trigger to [invoke the web request to the webhook URL of the runbook to start the runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks)(As the script should be ran every 5 mins said by author).

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <Webhook URI> -Method Post
```

For more details, you could refer to the [link](https://www.ciraltos.com/automatically-start-and-stop-wvd-vms-with-azure-automation/) mentioned in the [Github repo](https://github.com/tsrob50/WVD-Public/blob/f8d9dd7750fcb4c2bae191dd954724853a058833/StartStop-HostPoolVMs).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this article is different from the one I was following, I will take a look and let you know the result. I won't be able to do this for a few days yet as I have been told to prioritize on other things for the moment.